# How to redirect immediately user to login page (Default.aspx) on session time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, redirect

I want to redirects user if session time outs. Here I make one web user control that fetches session context in no session exist then it's redirects to login page.

Here is web user control code:

```
 public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session["Username"] != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            if (this.Page.User != null && this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

and this is my register method for this Web user control take effect to all pages from master page are like:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Admin/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="companylogo" TagPrefix="uc1"%>
```

Here problem occurs this not works fine. However when session expired then it's not redirect user to login page but it's give error like :

```
Server Error in '/EasyWeb' Application.

Sequence contains no elements

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Source Error: 


Line 53:             using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
Line 54:             {
Line 55:                 int user_id = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)Session["Username"])).Select(u=>u.Id).First();
Line 56:                 foreach (var item in db.Users.Where(u=>u.Id.Equals(user_id)).Select(u=>u).ToList())
Line 57:                 {

Source File: f:\EasyWeb\Admin\MasterPage.master.cs    Line: 55 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +847
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +113
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +344
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +23
   System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1 source) +211
   Admin_MasterPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\EasyWeb\Admin\MasterPage.master.cs:55
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

However this error raise when Session["Username"] has been expired default time. But this Web user control mechanism not works (however it worked in the past). Maybe there is something wrong with my code?

It's for my web security because this mechanism is very useful for protecting a web site from anonymous access from others.

Comment: here Context.Session not null try to check your Session["Username"] is not null then proceed and i think your session is null so you got the error of sequence contains no element.

Comment: u mean Context.Session["Username"] at if statement.

Comment: yes. put this condition  along with Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession. Because here you get user id from session["username"] but,if it is null then you cannot get your id

Comment: ya i update my question just see it..

Comment: @Akki - ya i follow ur suggestion but still there is error occurs. when session expires.

Comment: Can u give me code as u suggested or check my question.

Comment: @Akki - this techniques not works very well while please help me.