# how to alive session as long as possible in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

i 'm working with asp.net 3.5. i just want to session alive as long as possible (browser closed). here i just following this steps :

1) session timeout value changing to web config failed.
2) Using some external .ashx file and calling with javascript at master page like below technique:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SessionHeartbeat" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
public class SessionHeartbeat : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["Heartbeat"] = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

this javascript at master page :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function setHeartbeat() {
    setTimeout("heartbeat()", 300000); // every 5 min
}

function heartbeat() {
     $.post(
        "../SessionHeartbeat.ashx?Timestamp" + new Date().toString()",
        null,
        function(data) {
            //$("#heartbeat").show().fadeOut(1000); // just a little "red flash" in the corner :)
            setHeartbeat();
        },
        "json"
    );
}
</script>
```

but it's not give me the result that i want it.
please help me...

**------------------------------------Upadated---------------------------------------**

here i modify my jquery :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function setHeartbeat() {
    setTimeout("heartbeat()", 300000); // every 5 min
}

function heartbeat() {
     $.get(
        "../SessionHeartbeat.ashx",
        null,
        function(data) {
           beatHeart(2); // just a little "red flash" in the corner :)
            setHeartbeat();
        },
        "json"
    );
}
// beat the heart 
// 'times' (int): nr of times to beat
function beatHeart(times) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $(".heartbeat").fadeIn(500, function () {
            $(".heartbeat").fadeOut(500);
        });
    }, 1000); // beat every second

    // after n times, let's clear the interval (adding 100ms of safe gap)
    setTimeout(function () { clearInterval(interval); }, (1000 * times) + 100);
}
</script>
```

**----------------------------------Upadted----------------------------------------**

[image]

Comment: try using $.post?? and why r u calling  setHeartbeat(); from the success of get call??

Comment: Why would you like to do that ? Are you running web on single computer or are you using web farm ? Either way session state is maintained (by default) via session cookie - client send session cookie and server recognize cookie and grab session state from memory. If I clear this cookie, no matter what you do on server side, the session is lost. Also beware of client caching - adding some sort of "/SessionHeartbeat.ashx?Timestamp" + new Date().toString() instead just static url.

Comment: I assume you meant browser minimized instead of browser closed in your description. If you want the session to stay alive when there is no activity from the user perspective (i.e. they are not browsing around the site, keeping the sliding window open) in your "heartbeat" return some random data. We use this technique to have a small (sub 1hr) sliding session in our web.config but on a certain page where we know there is NO activity from the user, the session MUST stay open indefinitely (reading long documents). We heartbeat every 30s and return 4-8k of random text, this works flawlessly for us

Comment: Can you include relevant parts of your web.config?

Comment: sorry i forgot this line <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="SessionHeartbeat.ashx" validate="false" type="SessionHeartbeatHttpHandler"/> at <httpHandlers>

Comment: @Jeggs, can I ask why you *"return 4-8k of random text"*? I have a similar "keep alive" script, but I've not heard anything of a need for a minimum amount of data to be returned, and not heard of anybody saying the session ended prematurely

Comment: @freefaller During testing we found that the sessions were ending prematurely i.e. not being refreshed. We also had to ensure the response was not cached too. There may have been something else wrong, but we found sending back some chunk of data fixed this. I have this same site in a dev environment, when I get  a chance I will drop the return data and see if it keepalive still...

Comment: Thanks @Jeggs, would be interested to hear your findings :-)  (And I might just add 8k of random data to the return to keep safe anyway)

Comment: @Jeggs here i'm modofy my code to display heart beet from css but it's not display is that wrong with my jquery.

Comment: @freefaller I have just run this with no 'large response', a simple "OK" message to satisfy the get request and it seems to still be working just fine. I'll need to do some more thorough testing before I go changing my prod environment however! - But owe you some thanks as you have just saved us a little bandwidth. I will put this down to "attempting to resolve multiple issues at the same time" when we originally saw this.

Comment: Interesting @Jeggs - did you test on multiple browsers?  Wonder if IE,FF,Chrome deal with it differently

Comment: @freefaller I haven't tried multiple browsers yet. I will comment back if we end up putting it in to production, I don't think I will get around to testing everything for a while. I need to get it some real world attention, set my expiration back up to 45 mins and go through it properly. But it certainly seems to be working with a 2 minute timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for the OP.

**Web.config** - Set small timeout for testing

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2"/>
```

**Javscript** (in page for this example)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval = null;
    (function() {
        // keep me alive
        interval = setInterval(function (){
            $.get('keepalive.ashx', function (d) {
                $('#response').append(d + '<br/>');
            });
        }, 30000);
    })();


 // If we want to stop the interval....
    function Stop() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
</script>
```

This prints the sessionId in an element called **response** so we can see the session id.

**keepalive.ashx** Generic handler (needs System.Web.SessionState)

```
public class keepalive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // authenticated sessions
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Auth:" + context.Session.SessionID);
        }
        else
        {
            // guest
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("NoAuth:" + context.Session.SessionID);
        }
    }
```

Note: One thing that wasn't asked is is your keepalive supposed to be run on an authenticated session? If so, I wonder if there is also a cookie expiration issue?

Comment: it's not working..when i have to target this file from root folder and  at master page in admin folder i have to write path like  $.get('../keepalive.ashx', function (d) { or $.get('~/keepalive.ashx', function (d) {

Comment: correct, you will have to work out the relative path. The tilde (~) is a server side feature, so unless you are injecting the script server side and doing Server.MapPath to work out the relative location your tilde in javascript wont achieve anything.

Comment: how i know this is working in background with success.

Comment: In Chrome there is facility at Ctrl+Shift+j at Network Tab web can keep track of session works.

Comment: for more detail i include one snap shot with current page session key.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the handler to ensure it's being called. Also... I guess, how did you know it 'wasn't' working before? If it's working then you wouldn't exhibit the same issue surely?

Comment: Ok, break point bubbling says that file called properly. but approximately how much time it's take to getting expire. do you note no of mins, hr (with browser open).

Comment: No. this something like take regular time at session expiration.

Comment: So you are saying that the session is still expiring?

Comment: ya i mean i'm getting error like sequence not found from this session. hey can u have best solution of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575477/how-to-redirect-imideately-user-to-login-pagedefault-aspx-on-session-time-out).

Comment: I can't really comment on the best solution for you, best solutions are depending  on what exactly you want to achieve. As stated, we use this approach to keep a small SessionTimeout for most of a website, but certain areas of the site is required to keep the session alive indefinitely.