# how to maintain session state as long as possible with asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i just want to make session as long as possible. here i present my code how i maintain session with as long as possible with asp.net 4.0 with c# using ashx file.

here is my keepalive.ashx file :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="keepalive" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class keepalive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // authenticated sessions
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Auth:" + context.Session.SessionID);
        }
        else
        {
            // guest
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("NoAuth:" + context.Session.SessionID);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my calling code from master page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var interval = null;
        (function () {
            // keep me alive
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                $.get('../keepalive.ashx', function (d) {
                    $('#response').append(d + '<br/>');
                });
            }, 30000);
        })();


        // If we want to stop the interval....
        function Stop() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
</script>
```

and i change some properties from web config :

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2"/>
```

how ever this code not satisfied my needs..
please help me...

Comment: timeout = "2" means that your session will expire every 2 minutes. What you want to look at is disabling the session timeout in IIS. Not in code. IIS is the platform that maintains your sessions alive. .Net is only able to set properties that IIS can read and modify its behavior on. So lookup "iis session timeout never" in google for some answers.

Comment: this timeout to 2 mins are testing purpose here i want to know this handlers works and get alive. read my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857276/how-to-alive-session-as-long-as-possible-in-asp-net-3-5)

Comment: like i said: you want to look at IIS settings, not in-code or web.config... IIS can make your sessions last forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the timeout value for your application through web.config (which you already did to 2 mins) as follows

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      ...
      <sessionState timeout="525600 "/>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Or you can also set it on the server for all of the applications by setting the IIS config as given on [IIS site](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session)

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
   <system.webServer>
      <asp>
         <session allowSessionState="true" max="1000" timeout="525600" />
      </asp>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```